# Regex specific exclusions

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

I need a regex pattern that will match the **first occurrence** of a word, *not wrapped inside of an 'a' tag*, but can be wrapped inside of any other tag.

i.e. negative lookahead to see if matching word is inside of an a' tag, if so ignore and keep looking for a valid match.

Example strings

Payload 1:

```
<p>Sample 1 <a href="shouldNotMatchWrappedInA">wordToMatch</a> some random text 
to not be matched followed by wordToMatch, this should work.</p>
```

Expected Result 1:

```
wordToMatch ("Not the one inside of a' tags but the following one")
```

Payload 2:

```
<p>Sample 2 <a href="shouldNotMatchWrappedInA">wordToMatch</a> some random text 
to not be matched followed by <b>wordToMatch</b> this should work.</p>
```

Expected Result 2:

```
wordToMatch ("The one inside of the b' tags")
```

Payload 3:

```
<p>Sample 3 <a href="shouldNotMatchWrappedInA">wordToMatch</a> some 
random text to not be matched followed by wordToMatch followed by 
further occurrences of wordToMatch which should not be matched.</p>
```

Expected Result 3:

```
wordToMatch ("The second occurrence of the term")
```

Please help :'(

Language being used is Java

Comment: [H̸̡̪̯ͨ͊̽̅̾̎Ȩ̬̩̾͛ͪ̈́̀́͘ ̶̧̨̱̹̭̯ͧ̾ͬC̷̙̲̝͖ͭ̏ͥͮ͟Oͮ͏̮̪̝͍M̲̖͊̒ͪͩͬ̚̚͜Ȇ̴̟̟͙̞ͩ͌͝S̨̥̫͎̭ͯ̿̔̀ͅ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: Use some `xpath` queries instead - what is your programming language?

Comment: Java but processing the response of an ingested JCR query. XPATH may be an option.

Answer (score 0):

The simple pattern i can think of is:

```
(?:<a.*>)(\w+)(?:<\/a>)
```

In order to test please run the perl script:

```
$result  = "<p>Sample 1 <a href=\"shouldNotMatchWrappedInA\">wordToMatch</a> some random text to not be matched followed by <b>wordToMatch</b>, this should work.</p>";

$result  =~  m/(?:<a.*>)(\w+)(?:<\/a>).*(\1).*/;

print $2;
```

Pay attention you need to use the second matched group.
Unfortunately i cannot give you answer in JAVA.

Comment: I've tried this pattern but unfortunately it doesn't produce the desired result of wordToMatch **not** inside of an 'a' tag. Thanks for the reply though.

Comment: I updated the pattern, but this is a strange to search of next the same words